# Every projective module is a submodule of a free module?

Tags: free-modules

I've seen this statement on the internet but I could not find a proof. Actually this is true for any module I think. Can a proof be given as follows?

Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Take a generating set $X$ of $M$ over $R$. Then consider the free $R$-module $F$ over the set $X$. Hence $M \subset F$ and we are done. I hope this is not a nonsense idea.

Comment: Why $M \subset F$?

Comment: Every projective module is *isomorphic* to a *direct factor* of a free $R$-module.

Answer (score 2):

What you get with your $X$ (a generating set of $M$) and your $F$ (free on $X$)
is a **surjective** homomorphism $\pi:F\to M$, not an injection $M\to F$.

But if $M$ is projective, the surjection $\pi$ splits, that is there's
an injective homomorphism $\iota:M\to F$ with $\pi\circ\iota=\text{id}_M$.

Comment: Ok, that's the importance of projectivity! Thanks man.